# Big-O notation with two variables

Tags: algorithm, big-o

This originates from writing a program to [find the median of two sorted arrays](https://leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/) with size `m` and `n` respectively, with the time complexity of `O(log(m + n))`.

I can work out a solution of `O(log(m) + log(n))`. Does it meet the time requirement above?

I think it's positive because:

`log(m) + log(n) = log(m*n) <= log((m+n)^2) = 2*log(m+n) = O(log(m+n))`

Put another way, there exist `k = 2` and `m0 = n0 = 1`. For any `m > m0 and n > n0`, there is `log(m*n) <= k*log(m + n)`.

Is there a flaw, or am I correct?

More generally, given constant `a`, can we say `log(n^a) = O(log(n))` with the same reasoning?

---

Thanks to David's answer.
This is also mentioned by [Big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) on Wikipedia:

`"We may ignore any powers of n inside of the logarithms. The set O(log n) is exactly the same as O(log(n^c))."`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you're correct on all counts. Log grows slowly enough that the asymptotic class isn't very sensitive to the function inside.

Comment: So you say O(log(n^a)) = O(log(n)) ? Sorry I can't really understand the question.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Yes, assuming that the big-O notation treats *a* > 0 as constant, those are in fact the same function class.

Comment: Oh sorry :) I am looking on this and see something like O(n^a) = O(n). Should sleep a little. Of course with log it is true.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat. Thanks, David.